# Serializing a std::function from same codebase

Tags: c++, serialization

I've been using std::functions to make my classes more generic instead of making virtual members which would require declaring a whole new class that I only use in one place, however I'm stumped when it comes time to serialize the class.  I know that the idea of serializing random C++ code isn't going to work, but that's not what I need to do.  I know that the functions already exist somewhere else in the same binary, so I feel like there should be a way to do this.  I'm not opposed to doing this in some 'hacky' way either, although preferably it would work with gcc and MSVC

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/210732) to me.

Comment: I have a recursive serialization system in place to save my in game levels to disk, however I created a generic in game object that can perform a few different things depending on what you pass it for its two std::functions, and I'd prefer to somehow serialize the std::functions, and have some way to load them from disk (in the same exe, but a different invocation)

Answer (score 3):

If you map ids or "handles" to the set of functions that can be serialized, and do this in a deterministic, compile-time way, you can serialize the handles as an integer type. On deserialize/load, you can translate the handle into the relevant function pointer types using this deterministic map, and construct std::functions from that.

This is not so different from serializing/deserializing pointers in classes. This style of deserialization commonly consists of two steps: initializing POD types, then fixing up pointers in a second pass.

Answer (score 0):

we can serialize a std::function with it's parameters and then archive them into a file, or into the network, so that we can call the function(with specified parameters) after we reboot the machine, or more commonly, in another machine, which calls rpc.

here is an example:

The test code:
https://github.com/galaxyeye/atlas/blob/master/libs/serialization/test/function.cpp
The implementation:
https://github.com/galaxyeye/atlas/blob/master/atlas/serialization/function.h

for a easy to use RPC framework in C++, which enables the programmer to use remote function just like a native function, see project pioneer on my github.

i will finish it before next Monday.

for example, if you want to kill a process in all machines in a cluster, in your manager program, just write:

multicast_client client;
client.call("pkill", pkill, "a_bad_process");

we assume the server side program implemented a function like this:
void pkill(const std::string& process_name);

hope helps :)